# Disable Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

we are using [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap) in our Angular application. More specifically, we are using the [tooltip directive](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip). However, we do not want to display tooltips on mobile so we are looking for a way to globally disable the tooltip directive once the screen size falls under a certain threshold.

While there is a way to disable a single tooltip directive via the [tooltip-enabled attribute](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip#tooltip-directive), we are looking for a way to disable all tooltips with a single switch. What would be the best way to achieve this goal?

Many thanks

Comment: I would use a `@HostListner` to decide if a variable is true or false, and then use the var to enable or disable the tooltip. Or you can override via css the style

Comment: @fynn, I added a complete solution with a stackblitz example that uses a directive and a service to globally disable all tooltips using the tooltip-enalbed attribute. I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic solution using an angular directive `ToggleTooltipDirective` that sets the tooltip `isDisabled` attribute. This directive automatically targets every element with a `TooltipDirective`.

The directive is automatically added to the proper elements by angular by declaring it using the `'[tooltip]:not([toggleTooltip]),[toggleTooltip]'` selector.

> [Here is a working demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-ngx-tooltips-directive)

Using this solution, the tooltip is disabled using the API provided by ngx-bootstrap. Also, the toggling can be easily controlled via a service as shown below.

```
import { Directive, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { TooltipDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
import { TooltipControlService } from './tooltip-control.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[tooltip]:not([toggleTooltip]),[toggleTooltip]'
})
export class ToggleTooltipDirective implements OnDestroy {
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private tooltip: TooltipDirective,
    private tooltipControlService: TooltipControlService) {
      this.subscription = this.tooltipControlService.disabled$.subscribe(
        disabled => this.tooltip.isDisabled = disabled
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And here is a service so you can enable/disable from anywhere. The service also uses the `LayoutModule` from `@angular/cdk` to detect when the screen dimensions change and do the toggling.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TooltipControlService {
  private disabledSubject = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  disabled$: Observable<boolean> = this.disabledSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(public breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
    this.breakpointObserver
      .observe(['(max-width: 1280px)'])
      .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
        if (state.matches) {
          this.disable();
          console.log('Small viewport');
        } else {
          this.enable();
          console.log('Big viewport');
        }
      });
  }

  enable(): void {
    this.disabledSubject.next(false);
  }

  disable(): void {
    this.disabledSubject.next(true);
  }
}
```

Your app module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { ToggleTooltipDirective } from './toggle-tooltip.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, LayoutModule, TooltipModule.forRoot() ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, ToggleTooltipDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find a way to disable the tooltips completely. But by using a global style in your css you could solve this without JS.

```
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
    bs-tooltip-container {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

This would make the tooltips not display if the screen size is lower then 1280px.

Good luck!